# How to draw multiple lines (plots) using semilogy() at once?

Tags: matlab

I need to draw multiple lines using semilogy() with unknown input size. What I tried:

- hold on, doesnt work because it's get me ugly formatation: cut off title, and others.

What solution I guess solve my problem? Is make the semilogy function runs with a string input made by strcat().
Ps.: It works when using semiology with manual parameters.

```
`fileNames
strSemilogy="";
for (i = 1:numel(fileNames))
    T{i} = readtable(strcat("../Output/",fileNames(i),".txt")); % this isn't working
    i_ = string(i);
    strSemilogy= strcat(strSemilogy,strcat("T{",i_,"}.snr, T{",i_,"}.bErr,"," '-*'"));
    if (i < numel(fileNames))
       strSemilogy = strcat(strSemilogy, ", ");
    end
end
fig = figure(1);
set(fig,'color',[1 1 1]);
eval(semilogy(strSemilogy);`
```